# Who was the King of Scotland that asked Robbie to stand on Castle Rock and play the bagpipes?

Tags: british, scottish

Legend has it that there is a secret tunnel leading from Holyrood Palace to Edinburgh Castle, and that Robbie the Piper was one day asked by the King of Scotland to go down and find this tunnel by playing his bagpipes, and a group of people up on the ground would follow the sound of his bagpipes. According to the legend, the group on the ground followed the sound of the bagpipes until suddenly the music stopped. Robbie was never seen again, though it is said that his ghost still haunts the tunnels underneath Edinburgh to this day.

[Kelpies](https://discoverkelpies.co.uk/the-ghostly-piper-of-edinburgh-castle/)

> The King of Scotland asked him to be Edinburgh’s official piper and stand on the highest point of the Castle Rock to play. Every day Robbie blew his pipes so strongly that the soldiers guarding the castle, the people strolling on the Royal Mile and the monarch in Holyrood Palace heard him.
> [image: Robbie the piper]

I was just wondering, could it be worked out who the King of Scotland actually was?